# Can you use a face to slice other faces?

Tags: edit-mode

I am pretty new to Blender (currently working on my 3rd model). I need to tidy up the in/underside of the model to help reduce the impact on performance in the game it will be going into.

[image]

Is there a way I can use the flat face to slice the crystalline structures to make new edges so I can delete the unwanted sections?

Comment: Try the Boolean modifier. I'm not sure, but it might require volumes, not faces, so just extrude them (press E).

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods that are standing out to me.

One is the boolean modifier. For this, you need to make the crystalline structures a separate object. Than add a boolean modifier to one of the objects and use the union type. This will actually join the objects, the downsides are that it can create sloppy topology so it really depends on how willing you are to have n-gons and triangles in your mesh.

The other one is the intersect tool which is new with 2.72. For this you need to be in edit mode and have everything selected. The easiest way to find it is to use the spacebar search menu. Just search "intersect".

Here's a demo on the intersect tool:
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rwvxusuJXU&feature=youtu.be)

This won't join the two meshes like the boolean modifier, but instead it puts the verts where they need to be and leaves the user up to deciding what to do with the mesh.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just use the booolean, its easier.

Comment: I'm not so sure, I'm personally thinking that I would try the intersect tool. I find that the boolean modifier is a bit too buggy so I avoid it in most cases unless I really don't care about topology.

Comment: I don't really care about topology :) But you're right.